# hash_hmac() with RAW Binary OUTPUT in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, binary, base64, cryptojs

I have the php code to generate **hash_hmac**

```
key = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1',$public_key, $private_key,TRUE));
```

I've tried the **CryptoJS** library to solve it.

According to the documentation:

```
var public_key = 'msg',
    private_key = 'key';
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(public_key, private_key)
```

I don't know how to set the Raw Output to **Binary** like set `$raw_output` to `true` in php.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks:)

Comment: CryptoJS doesn't provide an encoder to get a "binary string". Why would you even need it? There are all sorts of problems when dealing with binary data in JavaScript. What's wrong with Hex (`hash.toString()`)?

Comment: Did you finally got it in js? I have the same problem, and need the raw output. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

php code

```
echo base64_encode(hash_hmac('SHA1', 'shanghai', '0', true).'beijing');
```

php output

```
xvBv49PpaYvXAIfy3iOSDWNQj89iZWlqaW5n
```

node code

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var buf1 = crypto.createHmac("sha1", "0").update("shanghai").digest();
var buf2 = Buffer.from('beijing');
console.log(Buffer.concat([buf1, buf2]).toString('base64'));
```

node output

```
xvBv49PpaYvXAIfy3iOSDWNQj89iZWlqaW5n
```